# What's the equivalent of nuget targets file in .net core

Tags: .net, nuget, coreclr

I've a got a library that I distribute via Nuget. In that package I have a .targets file which gets included in to the csproj of the consuming project (by nuget) so that MSBuild can execute a task during build (this effectively allows me to inject build steps in to consuming projects.) That task basically calls an executable that is included in the nuget package's "tools" folder.

I'm wondering how to achieve this functionality with .Net core and the new dotnet cli?

See the section "Import MSBuild targets and props files into project" at http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package

Comment: .NET Core uses .xproj and its build artifact is simply a NuGet package. There is no need to do anything like those for .csproj.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear.... using a .targets file in my nuget package allows me to inject build steps in to the project that is consuming my nuget package. dotnet/dnx doens't use MSBuild so how can I inject build steps in to the consuming project?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no support for custom actions. You will have to tell the consumers what to do with your package and what to run.

Btw, you can edit the nuget package after it was created and if anyone restores in a pre-dnx environment the targets will work but `dnu` doesn't run those scripts.